# Seeking public transport data for Berlin in csv or shp?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, overpass-api, transportation

I am looking for a shapefile or an Excel document (csv) with all the public transport stops (bus, underground, tram and train). I have searched on OpenStreetMap but I have problems downloading the data.

Do you have any suggestions for me or know where I could find such data?

When I go to https://overpass-turbo.eu/ and enter for example:

```
node
  [operator=BVG]
  ({{bbox}});
out;

node
  [operator="S-Bahn Berlin GmbH"]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

I get some results, but let us say 70% of the stations are missing. And the weirdest part is that I'm getting only `amenity=vending_machine`, not the "stops".

**To sum up**, my goal is to get a csv file, that contains:

1. Name of the station
2. What kind (U-Bahn [metro], S-Bahn, Bus or Tram)
3. Lat/Lng

I found this [wiki article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Berlin/Transportation) about the Berlin Transportation, but it is not complete.

Comment: is this what you're after? https://transit.land/feed-registry/operators/o-u33-s~bahnberlingmbh

Comment: Berlin GTFS Bus and Train (in German) https://daten.berlin.de/datensaetze/vbb-fahrplandaten-gtfs

Comment: If you seek open data the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: i have a similar problem, did you manage to get a file with the stops. I just need the Tram stations and line network for an assignment at Uni. Would you mind sharing it with me? Cheers.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164264)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164264)

Comment: Adding to Mapperz comment, here's a link to a global repository of GTFS feeds, inlcuding, of course, Germany: http://transitfeeds.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In wizard of overpass-turbo it looks something like this: `railway=tram_stop or public_transport=station`. See query below. Check osm for the exactly used types and tags:

[image]

When doing the query in overpass turbo make sure to zoom on that area you want to have your result at.

All stops in VBB:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“network="Verkehrsverbund Berlin-Brandenburg" and public_transport=stop_area”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “network="Verkehrsverbund Berlin-Brandenburg" and public_transport=stop_area”
  node["network"="Verkehrsverbund Berlin-Brandenburg"]["public_transport"="stop_area"]({{bbox}});
  way["network"="Verkehrsverbund Berlin-Brandenburg"]["public_transport"="stop_area"]({{bbox}});
  relation["network"="Verkehrsverbund Berlin-Brandenburg"]["public_transport"="stop_area"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Only Busstops:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“highway=bus_stop”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “highway=bus_stop”
  node["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
  way["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
  relation["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Subway and S-Bahn stops:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“public_transport=station”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “public_transport=station”
  node["public_transport"="station"]({{bbox}});
  way["public_transport"="station"]({{bbox}});
  relation["public_transport"="station"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Tramstops:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“railway=tram_stop”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “railway=tram_stop”
  node["railway"="tram_stop"]({{bbox}});
  way["railway"="tram_stop"]({{bbox}});
  relation["railway"="tram_stop"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Also note that OSM is never 100% accurate or complete. There might always be something missing or wrongly tagged.

If overpass turbo fails, you can alternatively extract your osm public transport data from this dataset: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html

Simply remove everything you dont need. This dataset does not contain relations like busways. But Tramtracks or Subwaytracks as well as stops.